# "copy" option not showing for UITableView row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am coming to this minor problem where I have implement to perform a copy popover to show when user is copying the item on the table view cell. But, for some reason it is not showing up the copy popover. Please, have a look at my code and see what I have done wrong.

This is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return action == #selector(copy(_:))
}
```

Here is my full code

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class PlaceDetailViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: PlaceDetailHeaderView!

    var annotation: ARAnnotation?
    var place: Place!
    var nearMeIndexSelected = NearMeIndexTitle()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        if self.place != nil {
            self.title = place.placeName
            self.tableView.delegate = self
            self.tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none
            self.loadDetailInfo()
            print("Place is not nil")
        } else {
            print("Place is nil")
        }

        // Configure header view
        headerView.nameLabel.text = place?.placeName
        headerView.headerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "blurimg.jpg")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(copy(_:))
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: PlaceDetailIconTextCell.self), for: indexPath) as! PlaceDetailIconTextCell
            cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "phone")
            cell.shortTextLabel.text = place?.phoneNumber

            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: PlaceDetailIconTextCell.self), for: indexPath) as! PlaceDetailIconTextCell
            cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "map")
            cell.shortTextLabel.text = place?.address

            return cell
        case 2:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: PlaceDetailIconTextCell.self), for: indexPath) as! PlaceDetailIconTextCell
            cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "web")
            cell.shortTextLabel.text = place?.website

            return cell

        default:
            fatalError("Failed to instantiate the table view cell for detail view controller")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the documentation for the `canPerformAction` method, you need to implement the `shouldShowMenuForRowAt` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
     return true
}
```

Only when this is implemented and returns `true` is the `canPerformAction` called.

Comment: mhmm.. I have implemented your snippet. But, for some reason it does not work .

Comment: Define "does not work". Is the `shouldShowMenuForRowAt` method being called? Is your `canPerformAction` method being called? What is and isn't happening exactly? Be clear and specific.

Comment: You need to implement the performAction method as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the 3 methods per the documentation, and you must not make a mistake and implement similarly named methods when Xcode sets up the trap for you with it's fabulous auto complete implementation.

Here is an example.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:))) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = cell.textLabel?.text
    }
}
```

Don't make the mistake of using Xcode's horrible auto complete and implementing:

`override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool`

Instead of the actually required method:

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool`